# TexLive 2011 does not allow custom installation

Tags: installing, texlive

I am trying to install TexLive 2011 according to instructions posted on its website here: http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

I used command `sudo ./install-tl --gui wizard` & I get 5-step gui. One of the steps says it would require close to 3GB of disk space for installation (which I cannot spare).

I remember running the same GUI some time back and it gave 'basic' and 'full' installation options, however this time it does not.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Also installing texlive from software center is not an option as I want to use tlmgr to keep my packages updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the above comment. `./install-tl -gui perltk` is the right command to run. This issue is closed now.